# Qual é a diferença de medição do tamanho e da coordenada nas Forms do C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Em meu projeto trabalho com a distancia de elementos e seu tamanho.
Porém em uma tela, de 600 por 600, ao inserir um objeto, de 100 por 100, ele aparenta ser bem menor que 1/6 da tela, e ao checar a distancia do ponto central do objeto para o Mouse

```
//descobrir o ponto central do objeto atual
Point ponto_central_obj = new Point(objeto.Location.X+50,objeto.Location.Y+50);
//calcular distancia X e Y
int distancia_x = ponto.X - ponto_central_obj.X;
int distancia_y = ponto.Y - ponto_central_obj.Y;
if(distancia_x < 0){distancia_x = distancia_x * -1;}
if(distancia_y < 0){distancia_y = distancia_y * -1;}
int distancia = Math.Sqrt((distancia_x ^ 2) + (distancia_y ^ 2));
```

E ao passar o mouse próxima a borda a distancia dada é 15 , 16 ou algo próximo, oque é bem menor que 50, que é a distancia minima do ponto central para a borda do objeto.

#### Perguntas

Com base nisso faço as seguintes perguntas.

- As coordenadas x e y não são a distancia em *pixels* do canto superior esquerdo da tela?
- Se não, como converter o valor para distancia em *pixels*?
- Elas são relativas de acordo com o tamanho do objeto pai?

Comment: Você pode dar mais detalhes? Mostre o que fez para chegar a estas conclusões. Em princípio, sem ver o que fez eu responderia sim para a primeira pergunta e terceira perguntas. Talvez seja por causa deste comportamento que você esteja achando algo estranho. Você não tem a tela inteira a sua disposição. Você tem a área que o objeto está sendo adicionado.

Comment: E que eu estou considerando a coordenada como distancia em pixels de tal ponto para o topo, no caso da coordenada X, e distância de pixels para o canto esquerdo, no caso  da coordenada Y, Estou certo?

Comment: Sim, é isto. O X, Y valendo 0,0 significa o topo esquerdo do objeto *container*. Portanto se você colocar qualquer outro objeto dentro o `Form` principal que é sua janela na posição 10,20, estará colocando na "coluna" 10 (portando em uma régua horizontal) da parte útil da janela e "linha" 20 (em uma régua vertical). Veja se era só isto para eu oficializar uma resposta. Ou esclareça se ainda não era isto que queria saber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As coordenadas x e y não são a distancia em pixels do canto superior-esquerdo da tela?
>
> Elas são relativas de acordo com o tamanho do objeto pai?

Sim, é isso. O x, y valendo 0,0 significa o topo esquerdo do objeto *container*. Portanto se você colocar qualquer outro objeto dentro do Form principal que é sua janela na posição 10,20 estará colocando na "coluna" 10 (portando em uma régua horizontal) da parte útil da janela (excluindo borda por exemplo) e "linha" 20 (em uma régua vertical).

As coordenadas cartesianas são sempre calculadas dentro do objeto onde outro objeto está sendo adicionado. Então isto deve estar dando a sensação de que está errado.

Você não está em um *canvas*, em uma tela livre para colocar o que quer, você sempre tem o objeto pai como "sua tela" do momento.